# Custom ArrayAdapter, listView, button

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I try to capture the click of the button in MainActivity but this didn't work with me.
How to do it.
I put toast in my getView it seems to work, but how to catch the click in MainActivity.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gestionmaps, parent, false);


    textView   = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView02);
    btn2       = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner02);
    btn        = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.del02);

    textView.setText(values.get(position));

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




            Toast.makeText(context, "btn "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "btn0 "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

return rowView;

}
```

Comment: Can you post code of your MainActivity as well, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have `onClick` of your button in `YourActivity` add this `android:onClick` line to your  `Button` xml file.

*list_item.xml*

```
<Button
    android:onClick="onClickButtonOne"
    .../>
```

*Activity.java*

```
public void onClickButtonOne(View v) {
    // button one onclick here.
    int position = listview.getPositionForView(v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's work just that i have to capture also the text of TextView and position of the item.

Comment: use `int position = lv.getPositionForView(v)` to get postion.

Comment: it's work thanks a lot another question, sorry for the disturbance but have you an idea how to get the Text of TextView that is in the same row like the button.

Comment: @volonte volonte you can directly get text from your array(which you are using to set adapter) by using position.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because when you click `button1` and `button2`, the clicks are consumed by **List Item**

**Solution :**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gestionmaps, parent, false);


    textView   = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView02);
    btn2       = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner02);
    btn        = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.del02);

    textView.setText(values.get(position));

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




            Toast.makeText(context, "btn "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "btn0 "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
rootView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
       // put logs here to check if it is executed when you click outside button area
      }

    });
return rowView;

}
```